# Query Exception: The class of the argument for the object comparison is incorrect

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data framework!

So I got the following error in eclipse console:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-6078] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The class of the argument for the object comparison is incorrect. 
Expression: [null] 
Mapping: [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToOneMapping[customerService]] 
Argument: [2]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=ServiceItem sql="SELECT t1.id_service_item, t1.tenant_id, t1.arrival_date, t1.departure_date, t1.negociation_observations, t1.requested_destination, t1.sale_type, t1.see_in, t1.value_negotiated, t1.fk_customerService, t1.fk_destination FROM service_item t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_service t0 ON (t0.id_customer_service = t1.fk_customerService) WHERE (((t1.sale_type = ?) AND (t1.fk_customerService = ?)) AND (t1.tenant_id = ?))")
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.incorrectClassForObjectComparison(QueryException.java:601)
```

But when i run the query in my database client the query works well!

Comment: The problem is with the JPA query, not the SQL, though what parameters are you using with the query that it would work in the database client?  According to the error, something is null - JPA and most databases require special handling of null checks using "is Null" etc.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the objects (JPA entities) as parameters, not the object IDs.